# Direct construction of a lifting

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to S^1$ be a continuous map such that $f(0,0) = 1$.

Using standard theorems about the existence of liftings (e.g., Proposition 1.33 of Chapter 1 in Hatcher's book Algebraic Topology), one can show the existence of a continuous map $g : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that

$g(0,0) = 0$ and $f(x,y) = e^{ig(x,y)}$, $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Is there a way to prove the existence of such a map directly, without using facts about covering spaces and fundamental groups?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a construction of such a map, but showing this is continuous should be as hard as establishing the covering space machinery restricted to these specific spaces. If you think this answer is absurd I recommend taking it as a demonstration of the power of the covering spaces perspective.

Define $g$ separately on each ray through the origin, so that we've reduced the problem to maps $[0,\infty) \to S^1$. 
If $f(x) = 1$, define $g(x)$ to be $2\pi \times \text{winding number of $f|_{[0,x]}$}$.
Let $g_1(x) = g(\sup \{y|y < x, f(y) = 1\})$. Note that this is already defined since $f$ at the supremum is $1$ by continuity. Now if $f(x) \ne 1$, then $f(x) = e^{it}$ for some unique $t \in (0,2\pi)$. Set $g(x) = g_1(x) + t$.